# Can we call parent method out side of the class

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I have parent and child class like following:

```
// class A
class A {
    public function test(){
        echo "CLASS A";
    }

}

// class b which is extending class A
class B extends A{
    public function test(){        
        echo "CLASS B";
    }

}

$class = new B;
$class->test();  //It's calling child class function.
```

Is there any way where I can call parent class method with `$class`? I know I can also create a object for class A and call the function, but I wanted to call parent class method from child class object.

Is this possible in php?

Comment: @hek2mgl I guess too :)

Comment: why negative vote in this , i wanted to know ... even i have posted after search on google and not find any relevant  answer for this.

Answer (score 3):

Try it with:

```
class B extends A{
    public function test(){        
        echo parent::test();
    }

}
```

More details here: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

Comment: @manish basically this the way to do. If you want to expose both functions outside of the class you have either a design error in your code, or you need to give those functions a different name if they aren't the same.

Comment: Sorry if I'm intruding, I'm new in the OOP but, in the child class isn't he overriding the the parent class' `test()` method?

Comment: Yes, he is, but he still can call the base class method from inside the class.

Comment: Inside the parent class its ok. i was knowing this. but i was curious about that. i think not possible to call parent class same name method from base class object.